# ctx.createPattern isn't working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

can someone please have a look at this. I have tried everything, however I can't seem to get this pattern to repeat. On the canvas I only get one to be drawn on the canvas but that is all. Can someone help please.

Thank you.

```
var canvasBg = document.getElementById('canvasBg');
var ctxBg = canvasBg.getContext('2d');

var gameWidth = canvasBg.width;
var gameHeight = canvasBg.height;

var imgSprite = new Image();
imgSprite.src = 'images/sprite.png';

function drawBg () {
var grassSrcX = 0;
var grassSrcY = 0;
var grassWidth = 74;
var grassHeight = 10;
var drawGrassOnCanvasX = 0;
var drawGrassOnCanvasY = 215;

ctxBg.drawImage(imgSprite,grassSrcX,grassSrcY,grassWidth,grassHeight,drawGrassOnCanvasX,drawGrassOnCanvasY,grassWidth,grassHeight);

var pattern = ctxBg.createPattern(canvasBg, 'repeat-x');
ctxBg.fillStyle = pattern;
ctxBg.fillRect(drawGrassOnCanvasX, drawGrassOnCanvasY, gameWidth, gameHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this myself after a lot of head scratching, and it was much simpler than I thought.

before drawing on the canvas that has been created on the HTML file, create another canvas inside the javascript file, or inside the `<script>` tag.

```
var canvasPattern = document.createElement("canvas");
```

Make sure that it has a different element Id, hint `("canvas")` instead of the old one that I used which was the Id from my HTML file `(canvasBg)`.

give it width and height

```
canvasPattern.width = 74;
canvasPattern.height = 10;
```

now create a context variable for this canvas to draw 2d shapes

```
var ctxPattern = canvasPattern.getContext("2d");
```

and now make sure that the image that will be used as the pattern to be drawn in the new created canvas.

```
ctxPattern.drawImage(imgSprite,grassSrcX,grassSrcY,grassWidth,grassHeight,drawGrassOnCanvasX,drawGrassOnCanvasY,grassWidth,grassHeight);
```

finally draw your patter on your old canvas (the one created on your html file) and let the pattern repeat.

```
var pattern = ctxBg.createPattern(canvasPattern, 'repeat-x');
ctxBg.fillStyle = pattern;
ctxBg.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 500);
```

Here is the the full script, hope this can help :)

```
var canvasBg = document.getElementById('canvasBg');
var ctxBg = canvasBg.getContext('2d');

var gameWidth = canvasBg.width;
var gameHeight = canvasBg.height;

var imgSprite = new Image();
imgSprite.src = 'images/sprite.png';

function drawBg () {

var canvasPattern = document.createElement("canvas");
canvasPattern.width = 74;
canvasPattern.height = 10;
var ctxPattern = canvasPattern.getContext("2d");

var grassSrcX = 0;
var grassSrcY = 0;
var grassWidth = 74;
var grassHeight = 10;
var drawGrassOnCanvasX = 0;
var drawGrassOnCanvasY = 215;

ctxPattern.drawImage(imgSprite,grassSrcX,grassSrcY,grassWidth,grassHeight,drawGrassOnCanvasX,drawGrassOnCanvasY,grassWidth,grassHeight);

var pattern = ctxBg.createPattern(canvasPattern, 'repeat-x');
ctxBg.fillStyle = pattern;
ctxBg.fillRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
}
```

Comment: You are missing the onload event for the image. You will have situations where the image will not draw at all if you call drawBg before the image has loaded. It can fool you into thinking it works because the image is cached and loads quickly, try emptying your cache and see if it works.. Also you should create the pattern canvas in the drawBg (if you dont wish to just use the image, you can scale the pattern) creating it outside will keep a reference alive wasting memory. Pattern is a copy of the canvas, so it (pattern canvas) does not need to stay.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the canvas object to the pattern as the repeatable image, you should change it to an image you want to repeat (I assume a grass in this case).

Comment: I tried replacing `var pattern = ctxBg.createPattern(canvasBg, 'repeat-x');` with `var pattern = ctxBg.createPattern(imgSprite, 'repeat-x');` , however it didn't do anything

Comment: @MohamedAdel Do you ever call the `drawBg` function? Are you sure the image is already loaded?

Comment: Yah, I am calling the drawBg function from inside the html file, just for testing. `<body onload="drawBg()">`... the image draws, however it doesn't repeat, and so I only have 1 little image in my canvas.